# Two wires for ac

Tags: ac

So I think I understand how ac power works. Am I right in saying that the electricity in standard two phase wire travels in waves through the black wire to the load and then in waves again back to the source through the white wire?

Comment: Not sure why this got a down vote. Is an honest question, just lacking in some understanding.

Comment: Read [Chapter 1 here](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_2/index.html), please.

Comment: The question in itself is valid, but: did you try to research a bit first?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite.
Normal two wire systems are not two phase, they are single phase.

Let's consider the voltage in a simple residential AC power system and assume your in North America. The voltage supplied from the utility company is a sine wave. This means the voltage is constantly changing in a repeating manner.

Lets start at some given moment in time. The voltage on the black and white wires is 0v. This voltage increases to 120V where black is positive with respect to white. The voltage will then decrease to 0v and then begin to increase again to 120V with white being positive with respect to black. This is why it is called an AC signal (alternating current).

This process of build up, reduction and reversal is called a cycle. This cycle occurs 60 times a second, or at a frequency of 60 Hz.

If we pretend the load is just a simple light bulb, you can imagine the brightness of the light bulb constantly changing from zero (when the voltage on the line is 0V) to its brightest and then back down again.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you it was helpful. but let try to rephrase this. if the electricity simply builds up and then is reduced why is there a need for a second wire

Comment: there must be a complete circuit, from source to load and returning to the source. Voltage is a potential difference, meaning it is in reference to something. If there was only one wire, and you turn on the voltage, what would you reference it to? It could be 1V or 1000V depending what the reference point is. Also, in order for current to flow, there must be a complete path.

Comment: Why can't a sink just have a supply pipe and faucet? Why does there have to be a drain?

Comment: so without a negative wire, the electricity spills over the counter and pisses off my wife? Good analogy, but if the asker doesn't understand the answer to his question, he probably wont understand the conclusion you're drawing.

Comment: @Josh, the second wire is required because the electricity is always flowing in a circuit, from the more positive wire, through the load, and back through the more negative wire.  The thing about AC is that the direction that the current is traveling around the loop reverses 120 times a second.  The electrons need to go somewhere in order to flow through the load.  It's possible to have a one-wire load, but they're impractical for normal things like light bulbs and motors.

Comment: @Josh, if you've benefited from the help you've received, please be sure to upvote and/or accept the answers that you found useful.

Comment: @DeanB As a side note, the electric field is the power and the current is a side affect.

Comment: @Kortuk, do you mean that the electric field is the motive power/motive force?  Real power would be V*I (or I^2*R, etc, etc), right?

Comment: @DeanB Electric field is what is actually causing things to happen, current is a side affect of it. For example, an electron will move on the order of meters/second while two wires with air will have the signal when you turn on your switch travel nearly the speed of light and that signal will cause current to start moving in the wire as it reaches that part of the wire.

Comment: @Kortuk, agreed.  I think we can all agree that for this question, certain details warranted omitting.  For example, using "conventional current" in the direction of hole flow rather than actual electron current.

Comment: @DeanB Current flows the direction of positive charge, electrons are negatively charged, I get tired of people complaining about that convention, but I wont start that argument.

Comment: @Kortuk, not complaining in the least.  Simply pointing out that the answer to a very, very basic question about alternating current is probably not the place to pontificate on the many nuances of electromotive force, hole current vs. electron current, sunspots, aliens, cursive, or migraines.  :)